# What's the difference between a deque and circular buffer?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, buffer, deque

I apologize in advance for my lack of data-structure education.

From my understanding:

- a fixed sized deque that serves as a memory can have its oldest value replaced (although we an remove new values)
- a circular buffer that serves as memory can also have its oldest values replaced

What is the difference between the two concepts? Are they the same thing? Is one a subset of another?

Comment: In the title you just say "deque", in the body you suddly say "fixed sized deque". Which one is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good related question would be this one: what's the difference between a queue and a linked list with a tail pointer? A queue adds to the end and removes from the front, which is the same thing you can do with a linked list with a tail pointer.

The difference is that one of these is an *abstraction* and one of these is a *concrete way of implementing that abstraction*. There are several ways to implement a queue, including a linked list with a tail pointer, a circular buffer, or even a splay tree. Similarly, there are things you can do to a linked list with a tail pointer that you wouldn't do to a deque, such as splicing large sections into or out of the list.

In your case, "deque" is the abstraction. You can think of a deque as "something where you can add and remove from both ends," and it could be implemented with a circular buffer, or a linked list, or a splay tree, etc. A circular buffer is one of many ways you can implement a deque, and there are other things you can do with a circular buffer beyond just implementing a deque.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

A deque is an [abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type), because it is defined by what you can do with it; what operations it supports. You can add and remove elements at either end of a deque.

A circular buffer is a [data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure), because it defined by how it is represented in memory, and how its state should be manipulated to fulfil the deque operations.

The relation between the two is that a circular buffer is an [implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implementation#Computer_science) of a deque.